# Data not being restored once you close the app and re open on one bottom navigator fragment

Tags: android, onresume

So I have this bottom Navigator (B, A, C) - my data is saved safely, but once I open A and close the app and come back, A is not restored, It shows that the generated data is not saved. B,A, C are all fragments. B and C are restoring and I have compared everything.

I tried the onSavedInstanceState but it is not working, So I am wondering how I should implement the onResume.

So question Is how to implement the onResume with my

> budgetDataArrayList

```
private ArrayList<BudgetData> budgetDataArrayList = null;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;


@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_budget, container, false);



            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);



        return view;
    }
```

Comment: What's the issue with onSavedInstanceState ? Can you show your implementation?

Comment: I have not implemented it, I am lost currently on how to.

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState` is not for persisting across quitting from the app, it's for config changes / low memory condition.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce how can I save the data then?

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-persistence/#2 ?

Answer (score 0):

When you close your app, all the variables, such as your `budgetDataArrayList`, gets deleted including `savedInstanceState`.

You should use `SharedPreferences` or `File` to store your data if you're going to close your app.

Comment: Why does that happen? can't I use the onResume method?

Comment: That's how application work, when you close it all variables gets deleted. Variables live in the RAM, when the application closes the RAM it occupies is freed. If you want a long term storage, you need to save it in the Storage. Which can be done by either `SharedPreferences` or `File`. `SharedPreferences` for small stuff like settings. `File` for large stuff like images. `onResume` only works if you're NOT gonna close the app. It only works if you minimize or rotate the app.